# `lsb_release -a` inside an `opensuse/tumbleweed` docker

Tags: docker, opensuse, getopt, lsb

## Context

When trying to install a python3 package using

```sh
python3 -m pip install absl-py
```

It fails if `lsb-release` package is installed (which is my case and mandatory).

After digging I've found, pip will internally call `lsb_release -a` which will lead to this error...
I can easily reproduce it using the following Dockerfile

## Protocol

Create this `Dockerfile`:

```
# ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/opensuse/tumbleweed
FROM opensuse/tumbleweed

RUN zypper update -y \
&& zypper install -y lsb-release \
&& zypper clean -a

RUN lsb_release -a
```

## Observed

```sh
docker build --tag=so .
...
 ---> 8330cfe918d5
Step 3/3 : RUN lsb_release -a
 ---> Running in 488762fb27a3
/usr/bin/lsb_release: line 122: getopt: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c lsb_release -a' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

## Tests

I've tried to install "gengetopt", "gnu-getopt" or "perl-Getopt-Long-Descriptive" without success (ed still the same error occurred).

## Workaround

One workaround is to install the meta package `lsb` unfortunately it take time (184 packages).

**I'm looking for a "smaller" package to fix it** (i.e. pulling less dependencies).

### Protocol

```
FROM opensuse/tumbleweed

RUN zypper update -y \
&& zypper install -y lsb-release \
&& zypper clean -a

RUN zypper update -y \
&& zypper install -y lsb \
&& zypper clean -a

RUN lsb_release -a
```

### Observed

```sh
docker build --tag=workaround .
...
Step 4/4 : RUN lsb_release -a
 ---> Running in 6d93c78f7a47
LSB Version:    core-2.0-noarch:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-noarch:core-2.0-x86_64:core-3.2-x86_64:core-4.0-x86_64:desktop-4.0.fake-amd64:desktop-4.0.fake-noarch:graphics-2.0-amd64:graphics-2.0-noarch:graphics-3.2-amd64:graphics-3.2-noarch:graphics-4.0.fake-amd64:graphics-4.0.fake-noarch
Distributor ID: openSUSE
Description:    openSUSE Tumbleweed
Release:    20201121
Codename:   n/a
Removing intermediate container 6d93c78f7a47
 ---> c11779133426
Successfully built c11779133426
Successfully tagged os:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the package owner of `getopt` using `zypper search -f <file>`:

```sh
15b83d17ed60:/ # command -v getopt
/usr/bin/getopt
15b83d17ed60:/ # command -v getopt | xargs zypper search -f 
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name               | Summary                                | Type
--+--------------------+----------------------------------------+--------
  | busybox-util-linux | Busybox applets replacing util-linux   | package
i | util-linux         | A collection of basic system utilities | package
```

So here, installing `util-linux` should be enough....